# Why does this code never discover Bonjour instances (mDNS)?

Tags: bonjour, mdns

I've taken this code almost directly from the dns-sd SDK sample, and yet, it does not find the services I search for.

There is no error, just none of the callbacks are called.  This is linked against the Apple Bonjour SDK on Windows 10 x32.

If I run "dns-sd -B _http._tcp" it finds many instances!

```
void DNSSD_API IterateServiceInstances(DNSServiceRef       sdRef,
                                   DNSServiceFlags     flags,
                                   uint32_t            interfaceIndex,
                                   DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
                                   const char        * serviceName,
                                   const char        * regtype,
                                   const char        * replyDomain,
                                   void              * context)
{
  puts("IterateServiceInstances is never called!");
}

void DiscoverSegments()
{
  printf("Discovering Segments...");
  DNSServiceRef client = NULL;
  DNSServiceErrorType err;
  err = DNSServiceBrowse(&client,
                        0,
                        0,
                        "_http._tcp",
                        "",
                        IterateServiceInstances,
                        NULL);
  if (kDNSServiceErr_NoError != err)
    printf("Error: Unable to enumerate Bonjour to find devices.\n");    

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    DiscoverSegments();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your socket message loop must keep track of ALL of the socket handles (client service refs) and pump them all while open...